# Converting HTML to pdf and save it to given location without opening "Save As" or "Download" window

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I am converting html into pdf. It is working fine. but when i try to save html into any location it gives me error `Network path not found`.
I am having some line of code

```
  #region Trying to convert pdf

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(htmlStringToConvert);
        iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
        #endregion
```

I am getting error at `htmlparser.Parse(sr)`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is in the htmlStringToConvert?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention.. htmlStringToCOnvert is a string that contains my html data

Comment: Ok, but what is the html data?

Comment: it have my html form's source code converted into string

Comment: Also, what error are you getting? This sounds like some malformed HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        DivMaster.RenderControl(hw);

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 10, 20);

        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);


        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
```

Add DivMaster (`div`) in design page and Add ur HTML code inside that DivMaster.
Note: Use `%` or `px` throughout HTML design.

Comment: Instead of htmlStringToConvert use DivMaster.i hope this will be working.

Comment: I will implement and then reply. But Thanks in Advance